# How to modify output on a bash terminal for all outputs

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal

I would like to be able to permanently edit my setup (I am running ubuntu) so that every time the terminal outputs something it adds something to the output.

An example of this would be to add a line of dashes at the start of the output.

What would currently happen:

```
./helloworld
Hello World!
```

What I would (say) like to happen:

```
./helloworld
--------------------------
Hello World!
```

I want this to happen no matter what the output is (so obviously in this case changing the "hello world" program wouldn't work!!)

This is just something I'm curious about more than anything else! I didn't know what to search to find it with google so if someone can at least point me in the correct direction I'd be very grateful!

Thanks

Comment: What is the purpose of this ? If you want to see where the output begins and ends , you could always modify your shell prompt

Comment: Thank you I that's exactly what I was looking for! I just didn't really know what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally , I do the opposite - I mark the end of previous output with my prompt:

```
-------------------------------------------------
DIR:/python|14:49|skolodya@ubuntu:
$ echo "HelloWorld"
HelloWorld
-------------------------------------------------
DIR:/python|14:50|skolodya@ubuntu:
$
```

The prompt itself can be modified in `.bashrc` or in any rc file that your shell uses to be something like this:

```
PS1='-------------------------------------------------
$ '
```

Add username or any other info as you wish

Answer (score 1):

If you use Bash you can trap the so called fake signal of DEBUG to achieve this:

```
trap 'echo -------------' DEBUG
```

and to make it permanent add the above to your `.bashrc` file.

Comment: Nice little hack. Learned something new today :)